# How can I track checkbox change-of-state?

Tags: winforms, treeview

I have a Windows Forms tree control with checkboxes.  I cannot seem to define an event handler for just a change in the node's checkbox status.
I am, however, able to catch the `NodeMouseClick` event but that event is fired for *all* clicks on the node and only provides the post-click status of the checkbox.   How can I know when a click on a node changes the state of the checkbox?  Do I need to maintain bound data behind the tree control?  I have been avoiding that because this is just a back-office tool I am developing.

I am using Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: Please specify language you're using in tags

Comment: There are BeforeCheck and AfterCheck events.